# Microsoft Teams for Ubuntu 20.04 will not start

Tags: 20.04, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the official MS Teams application to run on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. No matter how I install it, it will not display any sort of window when ran normally (i.e. clicking the icon in Applications, running `teams` if installed with apt, or running `snap run teams` if installed with snap).

When I run `snap run teams`, I get this error: `2022/02/18 10:15:43.002794 cmd_run.go:1039: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "/run/user/197001104/doc", got "/home/username/.cache/doc"`

When installed with apt and I run `teams`, I get no output and the process ends immediately.

The only way I am ever able to get a window to display is if I install with snap, `snap install teams`, then run it with `snap run --trace-exec teams`. Then it works as expected.

When not ran with `snap run --trace-exec teams`, I can see several processes running when I check `ps aux | grep teams`. These never close themselves and require a `kill <PID>` to exit.

I have tried the following versions with apt/dpkg:

```
1.4.00.26453
1.3.00.16851
1.2.00.32451
```

and the version snap installs is:
`1.4.00.26453`

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, clearing my cache using the following script, and any combination of the three.
https://gist.github.com/mrcomoraes/c83a2745ef8b73f9530f2ec0433772b7

**~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams/logs/teams-startup.log**

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: /usr/share/teams/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/native-utils/build/Release/native-utils.node: undefined symbol: _ZN5Utils32IsQuietHourOrDoNotDisturbEnabledEv
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:143:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:152:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
    at require (/usr/share/teams/resources/app.asar/external/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:173:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/teams/resources/app.asar/node_modules/native-utils/index.js:1:173)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/teams/resources/app.asar/node_modules/native-utils/index.js:3:3)
```

**snap version**

```
snap    2.54.3+20.04.1
snapd   2.54.3+20.04.1
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.13.0-28-generic
```

If any other info is needed or would be useful for troubleshooting, please let me know. I am all out of ideas.